# Hands on lab/testing with NAS

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, network-attached-storage, vmware-vcenter

My company has acquired a VMware system with 4 hosts and unfortunately i have no experience with NAS. Can anyone recommend a method to play with or learn how NAS works?

The system is a production environment, and id like to know how to work on this under the hood before something bad happens.

we have a hitachi array for the VMware drives and from what i understood a seperate HP-EVA for our SQL databases

Essentially, is there a way to create a virtual lab environment for NAS?

Thank you.

Comment: Since your question is vague, you won't get much of an answer. There are plenty of resources, free and paid (books!), to learn about SANs, fibre-channel and iSCSI. Use the disk arrays' and VMware's documentation to find out how to create LUNs and attach them to servers. Explore more advanced features like snapshots. Find out how to manage the arrays with command line tools and via their API.

Comment: Your question, as written, isn't clear. NAS = Network Attached Storage. What exactly do you want to know and how does that relate to VMware?

Comment: There is a various methods to deploy a NAS on your VMware setup. It would be great to know exact goals. In case you just want to test how NAS or SAN works, you can deploy a VM and setup software you need inside. As an example, the following guide might be useful: https://www.vmwareblog.org/building-freebsd-file-server/